# Can you identify this yellow translucent snake piece and sets it may come from?

Tags: piece-information, part-identification

[image]

Piece shown here a yellow translucent snake found in stacks of Lego. Wondering what it is and what sets it may come from so I can try and locate the rest and build it. Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you provide details on its size as well?

Answer (score 7):

It is part 98348 Minifig Weapon, Whip Bent with Snake Head and Pin Hole.

On [this page](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98348&idColor=16#T=C&C=16) you can find more info about this part, what colors it exists in, and all of the sets it appears in.

The part exists in this color in 3 sets: 41518 Glomp, 41519 Glurt, and in 9557 Lizaru Polybag.